# Loops and finstr

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch scripting. What I have:

- a text file that has last 7 days of log entries in increasing date order

Requirement:

1. Check for date string in `yyyy-mm-dd` format
2. Only when it finds the specific date for the first time in the file (that is current date) than it start looking for a specific keyword like "Success"

Comment: You should show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Also, when the Keyword "Success" has been found what should the batch file do? You have not given enough details for anyone to solve this problem, even if we wanted to. (should we write out the rest of the file, delete it from the file, what?)